# forming json data for d3 for stackable and nested charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have json data that looks like this:

```
[{"DateText":"Apr 2016","Agent":"wade","Talk":2},
{"DateText":"Apr 2016","Agent":"winop4","Talk":0},
{"DateText":"Apr 2016","Agent":"amy","Talk":2},
{"DateText":"Apr 2016","Agent":"GARY","Talk":0},
{"DateText":"Apr 2016","Agent":"kmahoney","Talk":0}]
```

I need it to look like this for d3:

```
["DateText":"Apr 2016", "Agent":"wade","Talk":2}, "Agent":"winop4","Talk":0}, 
"Agent":"amy","Talk":2}, "Agent":"GARY","Talk":0}, 
"Agent":"kmahoney","Talk":0}
"DateText":"May 2016", "Agent":"wade","Talk":5}, 
"Agent":"winop4","Talk":200}, "Agent":"amy","Talk":400}, 
"Agent":"GARY","Talk":900}, "Agent":"kmahoney","Talk":3}]
```

I would like to do this in JavaScript or even in d3. can anyone offer examples of good ways to do this?

Comment: Your question is a little broad.  Are you looking for a SQL solution, C# solution, frontend JavaScript solution?  For example, [here's  an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10404455/16363) detailing a dynamic sql pivot that would solve your problem.

Comment: sorry, hoping not to have to pivot tables in sql.  that's my last resort

Comment: Well that's kinda the problem with your question and why it'll probably eventually be closed.  What sort of solution are you looking for?  I can think of 3 different ways off the top of my head.  Which way is `the best way`, is a matter of opinion and off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: For me the best option would be to handle it in d3 or jquery.  But since I use a DataContext I could even deal with it tn c# What I would like to avoid is a dynamic query even though  I realize it is a possible solution. As stated in the question, it is not easy for me to maintain a pivot query for each stacked chart I might need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it this way and it does most of what I need without 'messy' sql.

```
  // all agents in set
  List<object> ops = m.GroupBy(x => x.Agent).ToList()
  .ConvertAll(c => (object)new { Agent = c.First().Agent});
  list = m
  .GroupBy(x => string.Format(@"""DateText"": {0}", x.DateText ))
  .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList()
  .ConvertdictionaryAll(c => (object)new { Datetext = c.DateText,  Agent 
  c.Agent, Talk = c.Talk  })));
  list.Add("keys", ops);
```

The keys for the Agents are in the last key of the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make your date of the main iterators, and then be able to access those agents.

```
[{
    "DateText": "Apr 2016",
    [{
      "Agent": "wade",
      "Talk": 2
    }, {
      "Agent": "winop4",
      "Talk": 0
    }, {
      "Agent": "amy",
      "Talk": 2
    }, {
      "Agent": "GARY",
      "Talk": 0
    }, {
      "Agent": "kmahoney",
      "Talk": 0
    }]
  }, {
    "DateText": "May 2016",
    [{
        "Agent": "wade",
        "Talk": 5
      }, {
        "Agent": "winop4",
        "Talk": 200
      }, {
        "Agent": "amy",
        "Talk": 400
      }, {
        "Agent": "GARY",
        "Talk": 900
      }, {
        "Agent": "kmahoney",
        "Talk": 3
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```